# Loading images from Firebase Database using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am currently having trouble loading images which I've uploaded to Firebase Storage and saved URL to Firebase Database. I'm using Firebase UI and Glide library to load images. I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage), and below is my code:

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Students")
            .limitToLast(50);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Students> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Students>()
                    .setQuery(query, Students.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Students, StudentsHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public StudentsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_students, parent, false);
            return new StudentsHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Students model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
            holder.setImage(model.getImages(), getApplicationContext());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mRecycerView.setAdapter(FirebaseAdapter);
```

This is my Students.class:

```
public class Students {

public String name;
public String price;
public String image;

public Students() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Students.class)
}

public Students(String name, String price, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getImages() {
    return image;
}
```

}

And this is StudentsHolder.class:

```
public class StudentsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView nameTV;
TextView priceTV;
ImageView imageIV;

public StudentsHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    nameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    priceTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    imageIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
}


public void setName(String studentName) {
    nameTV.setText(studentName);
}

public void setPrice(String studentPrice) {
    priceTV.setText(studentPrice);
}

public void setImages(String image, Context context) {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Students").child(24680).child(image);   // this is just an example
    Glide.with(context).load(storageReference).into(imageIV);    
}
```

This is how Firebase Database looks like:
[image]

I wonder is this the way I can get image URLs from Firebase Database? I've seen solutions which use *addValueEventListener* with  *onDataChange* and *onCancelled*, but that's kinda loading my data slowly?!

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: The `image` values look invalid, as they're missing `//` after the `https:`.

Comment: Thanks, actually the URL is okay, that's just an example, I forgot to write the //.

The error is as follows:
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
    Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.